# Are data type declarators like "int" and "char" stored in RAM when a C program executes?

Tags: c, data

When a C program is running, the data is stored on the heap or the stack. The values are stored in RAM addresses. But what about the type indicators (e.g., `int` or `char`)? Are they also stored?

Consider the following code:

```
char a = 'A';
int x = 4;
```

I read that A and 4 are stored in RAM addresses here. But what about `a` and `x`? Most confusingly, how does the execution know that `a` is a char and `x` is an int? I mean, is the `int` and `char` mentioned somewhere in RAM?

Let's say a value is stored somewhere in RAM as 10011001; if I am the program which executes the code, how will I know whether this 10011001 is a `char` or an `int`?

What I don't understand is how the computer knows, when it reads a variable's value from an address such as 10001, whether it is an `int` or `char`. Imagine I click on a program called `anyprog.exe`. Immediately the code starts executing. Does this executable file include information on whether the variables stored are of the type `int` or `char`?

Comment: This information is totally lost at run-time.  You (and your compiler) have to make sure in advance that the memory will be interpreted correctly.  Is this the answer you were after?

Comment: What I don't understand is how does the computer know lets when it reads a variable's value from and address such as 10001 if is an int or char. Imagine I click on a program called anyprog.exe. Immediately the code starts executing. Does this exe file include information about if the variables are stored as in or char?

Comment: Because you declared it as `char a` or `int x`.

Comment: ok Im asking is that information (if it is char or int) stored in exe file and later in RAM during execution?

Comment: Well, what do you do with the char or int?  Do you write the char to stdout?  The C program only needs to know the address of the char to write it to stdout; it doesn't need to know its type.  Do you add 1 to the int?  The C program still only needs to know the address of the int.  It assumes you know what you are doing; if you add 1 to a char, expect funny things to happen.  Most of the type checking is done at compile-time, not runtime.

Comment: If I want to write a char to stdout, and when I execute the program how does stdout know that binary variable at a RAM register is a char or int?

Comment: It doesn't.  Because it assumes that you know what you are doing, it takes whatever it finds at the memory address you provided, and writes it to stdout.  If whatever was written corresponds to a readable character, it will eventually show up on someone's console as a readable character.  If it doesn't so correspond, it will appear as gibberish, or possibly a random readable character.

Comment: @user16307 The short answer is that in statically typed languages, whenever you print out a char, the compiler will *produce different code* than it would for printing out an int. At runtime there is no longer any knowledge that `x` is a char, but it's the char-printing code that gets run, because that's what the compiler selected.

Comment: I think I couldn't put my question well. If program reads a register value it has to interpret via ASCII code if it is char for example if it reads 65 it will out A because it is a char. But if it was int it would out as 65. Isnt it? So I think it has to know of the stored value is int char string ect? Where am I wrong here?

Comment: @user16307 It's always stored as the binary representation of the number 65. Whether it gets printed out as 65 or as A **depends on the code** that your compiler produced to print it out. There is no metadata next to the 65 that says it's actually a char or an int (at least, not in statically typed languages like C).

Comment: The fully understand the concepts you ask about here and implement them by yourself, you might want to take a compiler course, e.g. [coursera's one](https://class.coursera.org/compilers/lecture/preview)

Comment: No, there's not information next to the variable. But there is information next to the instructions that use that variable. E.g. "load a short from memory" is a different instruction from "load an int from memory", and "print a char" is different from "print an int".

Comment: When asking a question like this, please be sure to tag it with the programming language (**[tag:C]** in this case). Different languages/runtime environments treat this topic differently.

Comment: why is everybody forgetting about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information !?! I know it's a C++ extension, but come on - ain't it worth a mention at least?

Comment: @vaxquis I don't think the OP is asking about the sort of things RTTI addresses. The OP is asking something way more basic: how does a computer "know" whether the contents of a register or a memory location is an int, or a char, or whatnot. And the answer is "the computer doesn't, but the compiler will generate code that treats the stored value differently according to the type at compile time."

Comment: @AndresF. I don't know what OP asked, since his question was so garbled I barely understood it until a chain of edits made something more readable from it... Also, saying just "the computer doesn't" is not true - the computer often *does* know, both in C++, Java, Python, you name it. C is kind of exceptional here, due to being a legacy language. OP was clueless, and no answer that doesn't at least *mention* the type information retention policies in programming languages ain't good IMO. That's why Jörg's answer got my +1, not Ryan's one.

Comment: @vaxquis I'd argue that the computer *doesn't* know. The compilers for C++, Java, etc. produce additional code to handle this information -- which again, I think it's a more advanced topic than what the OP is asking about -- but the hardware knows nothing of it. You have to keep track of this *because* the computer doesn't know how to do it; C++ (for example) merely generates code for this, so that you don't have to write it yourself. Compare this to writing assembly code. This is why I consider Ryan's answer the best for the kind of knowledge level I assume the OP to have.

Comment: To be more clear let me put it this way: Lets say I'm the CPU and just after the *.exe clicked and memory allocation is done, I start my job fetching instructions and data from the RAM. When I (as CPU) receive instructions and variable values byte by byte, do I also receive any info about the data types? That was my question. And as far as I understood, since the compiler links the related data to related instructions(by pointing addresses) no need to know it. Compiler prepared it all. Is that right for all languages?

Comment: @vaxquis Jorg's answer is pretty good as well, and has my +1.

Comment: I'd suggest you produce a mixed mode listing from your program, where you can see what line in C generates what line(s) in assembler. Check http://www.systutorials.com/240/generate-a-mixed-source-and-assembly-listing-using-gcc/

Comment: @user16307 `Is that right for all languages?` - Although the answer would greatly depend on what you mean by "language" (e.g. C# vs .NET), I wouldn't say so. Some languages (e.g. C++ with RTTI) retain type information, but doesn't actively use it. Languages with a virtual machine, dynamic/weakly-typed languages, interpreted languages, scripting languages etc. on the other hand, *have to* know the the type of the data to be able to do anything with it.

Comment: @vaxquis does C# for instance retain type information or is like C execution?

Comment: C# retains type information (and even generic type information via type reification) for the .NET VM (CLR) to be able to work with the data properly. The keyword `dynamic` wouldn't have worked otherwise, among other things. It makes the compiler "blind" to the type of the object, and allows you to rely only on runtime information when it comes to method binding, polymorphism etc.

Comment: So if I am the CPU, and when a C# program compiled assembled, linked ect. and eventually converted to binary machine code and when this executed are you saying I(as CPU) receive type information about the variables from the RAM registers??

Comment: @user16307 try to *not* think of CPU in first person, it's a fallacious abstraction. CPU is just a mathematical machine. It stores data and executes arithmetical/logical instructions, processing the data. It doesn't "receive" anything. If you're executing C# program, you're actually invoking a virtual machine as a "virtual CPU" to process the executable code in abstract way - in some situations the CPU as itself doesn't even receive variable values, as VM can (and *will*, see Java's HotSpot's and CLR's documentation) remove the unneeded code as it sees fit. CPU doesn't *know* anything!

Comment: ohh, i started to get more and more confused... I thought Ryan's asnwer had put an end to my pursuit to relief the foggy picture of understanding how variables types processed..

Comment: @user16307 programmers deal with proper *abstractions*, not with *CPUs*. It's the common beginner's pitfall to focus on the process's internals, losing the sight of the process itself. Unless you're programming assembly and/or microcontrollers, only learn & assume as much about the platform as you *must*; with high-level languages, you have absolutely *no* guarantee that your code will even *hit* the CPU. As to the CPU, on the other hand - it's an abstraction itself. In reality, everything important happens at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit

Comment: "you have absolutely no guarantee that your code will even hit the CPU" this sentence totally shocked me. I thought all the activity done by CPU when a program executes.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26691/discussion-on-question-by-user16307-are-data-type-identifiers-like-int-and-ch).

Comment: @vaxquis: I agree that programmers should deal with abstractions which, depending upon the kind of code one is doing, should often be somewhat detached from CPU semantics.  On the other hand, I think it has historically been useful to regard programs as running on abstract machines which loosely specify certain aspects of behavior which is not defined by the C standard.  For example, under one model which which almost every microcomputer compiler has been able to support with appropriate compiler settings (and which most supported with default settings), the code `int x = INT_MAX; y=x+1;`....

Comment: ...may set `x` to a "value" which, each time it's read, may behave as an arbitrarily number (not necessarily representable by any data type) which is congruent to `INT_MAX+1u` mod `UINT_MAX+1`.  If code would be equally happy with any such number that could result from reading `y`, such a model would eliminate the need for overflow checking, while allowing some compilers to code which runs faster than would any strictly-compliant C code meeting the same requirements.  IMHO, standardizing some normative abstract machines would not only allow many kinds of code to be written more clearly...

Comment: ...than would be possible in strictly-compliant C, but would also improve runtime efficiency.  On some platforms, the optimal code for `y=(int)(x+1L);` may be significantly slower than would be the optimal code to compute `y=x+1` under the earlier-described execution model.  Allowing further "optimizations" to `y=x+1;` in cases where overflow might occur will make code slower rather than faster if it means that optimizable constructs almost never appear in useful programs.

Comment: @supercat I'd like to add that "slower" and "faster" would require first a) to have a measurable and reproducible performance bottleneck, b) to profile the code to expose the bottleneck, c) to verify that a change in behaviour produces a consistent and proportionally significant change of code execution. code ain't slow nor fast, it's the execution that is - and execution *is* tied to a machine and runtime conditions. I'd advocate *against* talking about code speed when newbies are near, at all... too many misconceptions arise.

Comment: my favouritte example is the well-known http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array , although there are literally hundreds of such examples; OTOH, I've routinely stopped using floating-point division, in cases where it can be replaced by inverse multiplication, a couple of years ago; some people would call it "premature optimization" - yet when I see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875464/huge-performance-difference-26x-faster-when-compiling-for-32-and-64-bits, I just laugh to myself for avoiding such trouble beforehand

Comment: If a programmer wants to (1) compute the expression `x+y > z;` when the `x+y` can be expressed as `int`, and (2) arbitrarily yield 0 or 1, without launching nuclear missiles, when it can't, a good language shouldn't require a programmer to spend more effort meeting the second requirement than the first.  Advocates for compiler writers argue that even if new compilers increase the amount of effort required for programmers to meet requirement #2, the performance gains will be worth it.  I call hogwash.

Comment: @vaxquis Can you name a hardware component on a PC board which executes code rather than a CPU. Im still searching  for an explanation about your comment "you have absolutely no guarantee that your code will even hit the CPU". Which component may a code hit and be executed if not the CPU? (probably in C# case)

Comment: @user16307 I've already answered this in http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/26691?m=23287027#23287027 (about the code)  & http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/26691?m=23287173#23287173 (about the components) - if you need a *concrete* example of code executed outside of CPU - GPU shaders or remote machines may execute some of the code if e.g. using [MPI](http://www.open-mpi.org/) or APP or e.g. *if the OS or runtime sees that as a viable option* - also, please ask further questions in chat, as requested by [moderator](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/25936/yannis).

Comment: The reason Im asking Im searching the books and web and all teach the subject as if CPU is only responsible unit for code execution. I will go crazy since if what you say is true I feel like I will never have the right picture of code execution in C# case.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

To address the question you've posted in several comments(which I think you should edit into your post):

> What I don't understand is how does the computer know lets when it reads a variable's value from and address such as 10001 if is an int or char. Imagine I click on a program called anyprog.exe. Immediately the code starts executing. Does this exe file include information about if the variables are stored as in or char?

## So lets put some code to it.  Let's say you write:

```
int x = 4;
```

And let's assume that it gets stored in RAM:

```
0x00010004: 0x00000004
```

The first part being the address, the second part being the value.  When your program(which executes as machine code) runs, all it sees at `0x00010004` is the value `0x000000004`.  It doesn't 'know' the type of this data, and it doesn't know how it is 'supposed' to be used.

So, how does your program figure out the right thing to do?  Consider this code:

```
int x = 4;
x = x + 5;
```

We have a read and a write here.  When your program reads `x` from memory, it finds `0x00000004` there.  And your program knows to add `0x00000005` to it.  And the reason your program 'knows' this is a valid operation, is because the compiler ensures that the operation is valid through type-safety.  Your compiler has already verified that you can add `4` and `5` together.  So when your binary code runs(the exe), it doesn't have to make that verification.  It just executes each step blindly, assuming everything is OK(bad things happen when they are in fact, not OK).

## Another way to think of it is like this.  I give you this information:

```
0x00000004: 0x12345678
```

Same format as before - address on the left, value on the right.  What type is the value?  At this point, you know just as much information about that value as your computer does when it's executing code.  If I told you to add 12743 to that value, you could do it.  You have no idea what the repercussions of that operation will be on the whole system, but adding two numbers is something you're really good at, so you *could* do it.  Does that make the value an `int`?  Not necessarily - All you see is two 32-bit values and the addition operator.

## Perhaps some of the confusion is then getting the data back out.  If we have:

```
char A = 'a';
```

How does the computer know to display `a` in the console?  Well, there are a lot of steps to that.  The first is to go to `A`s location in memory and read it:

```
0x00000004: 0x00000061
```

The hex value for `a` in ASCII is 0x61, so the above might be something you'd see in memory.  So now our machine code knows the integer value.  How does it know to turn the integer value into a character to display it?  Simply put, the compiler made sure to put in all of the necessary steps to make that transition.  But your computer itself(or the program/exe) has no idea what the type of that data is.  That 32-bit value could be anything - `int`, `char`, half of a `double`, a pointer, part of an array, part of a `string`, part of an instruction, etc.

---

Here's a brief interaction your program (exe) might have with the computer/operating system.

Program: I want to start up.  I need 20 MB of memory.

Operating System: *finds 20 free MB of memory that aren't in use and hands them over*

(The important note is that this could return *any* 20 free MB of memory, they don't even have to be contiguous.  At this point, the program can now operate within the memory it has without talking to the OS)

Program: I'm going to assume that the first spot in memory is a 32-bit integer variable `x`.

(The compiler makes sure that accesses to other variables will never touch this spot in memory.  There's nothing on the system that says the first byte is variable `x`, or that variable `x` is an integer.  An analogy: you have a bag.  You tell people that you will only put yellow colored balls in this bag.  When someone later pulls something out of the bag, then it would be shocking that they would pull out something blue or a cube - something has gone horribly wrong.  The same goes for computers: your program is now assuming the first memory spot is variable x and that it is an integer.  If something else is ever written over this byte of memory or it's assumed to be something else -  something horrible has happened.  The compiler ensures these kinds of things don't happen)

Program: I will now write `2` to the first four bytes where I'm assuming `x` is at.

Program: I want to add 5 to `x`.

- Reads the value of X into a temporary register
- Adds 5 to the temporary register
- Stores the value of the temporary register back into the first byte, which is still assumed to be `x`.

Program: I'm going to assume the next available byte is the char variable `y`.

Program: I will write `a` to variable `y`.

- A library is used to find the byte value for `a`
- The byte is written to the address the program is assuming is `y`.

Program: I want to display the contents of `y`

- Reads the value in the second memory spot
- Uses a library to convert from the byte to a character
- Uses graphics libraries to alter the console screen(setting pixels from black to white, scrolling one line, etc)

(And it goes on from here)

What you're probably getting hung up on is - what happens when the first spot in memory is no longer `x`? or the second is no longer `y`?  What happens when someone reads `x` as a `char` or `y` as a pointer?  In short, bad things happen.  Some of these things have well-defined behavior, and some have undefined behavior.  Undefined behavior is exactly that - anything can happen, from nothing at all, to crashing the program or the operating system.  Even well-defined behavior can be malicious.  If I can change `x` to a pointer to my program, and get your program to use it as a pointer, then I can get your program to start executing my program - which is exactly what hackers do.  The compiler is there to help make sure we don't use `int x` as a `string`, and things of that nature.  The machine code itself is not aware of types, and it will only do what the instructions tell it to do.  There is also a large amount of information that's discovered at run-time: which bytes of memory is the program allowed to use?  Does `x` start at the first byte or the 12th?

But you can imagine how horrible it would be to actually write programs like this(and you can, in the assembly language).  You start off by 'declaring' your variables - you tell yourself that byte 1 is `x`, byte 2 is `y`, and as you write each line of code, loading and storing registers, you (as a human) have to remember which one is `x` and which one is `y`, because the system has no idea.  And you (as a human) have to remember what types `x` and `y` are, because again - the system has no idea.

Comment: Amazing explanation. Only the part  you wrote "How does it know to turn the integer value into a character to display it? Simply put, the compiler made sure to put in all of the necessary steps to make that transition." is still foggy for me. Lets say the CPU fetched 0x00000061 from the RAM register. From this point are you saying there are other instructions(in the exe file) which make that transition to what we see on the screen?

Comment: @user16307 yes, there are additional instructions.  Each line of code you write can potentially be turned into many instructions.  There are instructions to figure out what character to use, there are instructions for which pixels to modify and what color they change to, etc.  There's also code that you don't really see.  For example, using std::cout means you're using a library.  Your code to write to the console may only be one line, but the function(s) you call will be more lines, and each line can turn into many machine instructions.

Comment: I understand your explanation makes sense. But some here replied my question: "Doesnt exe file include information about what address is what type of data?" as following: "No. It doesn't. The compiler knows what code it has to put in the binary. There is no point in keeping this information around." Im confused..

Comment: @user16307 That's also true.  The exe doesn't know where things will be in memory, because that's going to change from one run to the next.  Part of declaring a variable `int x = 4` and turning it into machine code will create instructions that say something along the lines of 'I[the program] am going to use address `0x22222228`'.  Let's say your PC has 8 GB of RAM.  You start up, and the first thing you do is run your program.  Maybe 200 MB is taken up so far, so your program's memory starts around 201 MB.  Now you restart the computer, and have an Anti-virus running.  It's a hog and...

Comment: it takes 1 GB of memory.  So now your PC is using the original 200 MB, plus 1 GB on top of that.  The lowest memory spot your program can use is the 1,201 MB.  It's a bit more involved than that, but that's the basics of it.  There's a lot a program does to request memory from the operating system and to hold on to it(so that another program doesn't come along and write over your memory while your program is running).

Comment: Im completely lost... CPU follows the instructions from the exe file's machine codes. The instruction codes must know of a variable at an address is char or not. Otherwise how can console or text file outputs a character instead of int? There must be some info code for the CPU operations in the exe?

Comment: @user16307 I added an edit which might clear things up.

Comment: @user16307 `Otherwise how can console or text file outputs a character instead of int`  Because there is a different sequence of instructions for outputting the contents of a memory location as an integer or as an alphanumeric characters. The compiler does know about the variables types, and chooses the appropriate sequence of instructions at compile time, and records it in the EXE.

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant: exactly. See what happens if you have a printf() call but mix the data types with your format specifiers.

Comment: I would find a different phrase for "The byte code itself," as byte code (or bytecode) usually refers to an intermediate language (like Java Bytecode or MSIL), which might actually store of this data for the runtime to leverage. Plus it's not entirely clear what "byte code" is supposed to refer to in that context. Otherwise, nice answer.

Comment: @Ryan I think I started to understand now. 1-) The OS allocates some memory each time the *.exe starts execution. And all addresses where the program points are within that allocated memory. 2-) Since compiler took care of machine code conversion, the *.exe program's instruction codes are tied to related registers. *.exe fetches the "pointed" data from the register address and manipulates it. this pointing linking is done by compiler already. Did I get it right now? One last question: The moment we click on *.exe, how does OS know right amount of memory to allocate before *.exe executes?

Comment: @user16307 it doesn't. It is the responsibility of the compiler or the programmer (depending on the language) to request (allocate) and return (deallocate) memory correctly. See, for example, [`malloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/). All this is coded into machine instructions as part of the process of turning your program into machine code, which is done by the compiler.

Comment: @BoristheSpider It sorta does. The OS has to load the program into memory when it first starts up, by allocating and loading the program's code and data segments (whose lengths are encoded in the .exe file). The program can then, afterwards, allocate more memory from the OS if it wishes to.

Comment: @Ryan if you read under my question the last comments, some commentators claim this story you pictured is completely different in C++ and C# case? do you have information about it?

Comment: @user16307 Try not to worry about C++ and C#. What these people are saying is way above your current understanding of how computers and compilers work. For the purposes of what you're trying to understand, the hardware does NOT know anything about types, char or int or whatever. When you told the compiler some variable was an int, it generated executable code to handle a memory location AS IF it were an int. The memory location itself contains no info about types; it's just that your program decided to treat it as an int. Forget everything else you heard about runtime type information.

Answer (score 43):

I think your main question seems to be: "If the type is erased at compile-time and not retained at runtime, then how does the computer know whether to execute code wich interprets it as an `int` or to execute code which interprets it as a `char`?"

And the answer is … the computer doesn't. However, the compiler *does* know, and it will have simply put the correct code in the binary in the first place. If the variable were typed as `char`, then the compiler wouldn't put the code for treating it as an `int` in the program, it would put the code to treat it is a `char`.

There *are* reasons to retain the type at runtime:

- Dynamic Typing: in dynamic typing, type checking happens at runtime, so, obviously, the type has to be known at runtime. But C isn't dynamically typed, so the types can be safely erased. (Note that this is a very different scenario, though. Dynamic Types and Static Types aren't really the same thing, and in a mixed-typing language, you could still erase the static types and only keep the dynamic types.)
- Dynamic Polymorphism: if you execute different code based on the runtime type, then you need to keep the runtime type around. C doesn't have dynamic polymorphism (it doesn't have any polymorphism at all, really, except in some special hard-coded cases, e.g. the `+` operator), so it doesn't need the runtime type for that reason. However, again, the runtime type is something different to the static type anyway, e.g. in Java, you could theoretically erase the static types and still keep the runtime type for polymorphism. Note also, that if you decentralize and specialize the type-lookup code and put it inside the object (or class), then you also don't necessarily need the runtime-type, e.g. C++ vtables.
- Runtime Reflection: if you allow the program to reflect on its types at runtime, then you obviously need to keep the types at runtime. You can easily see this with Java, which keeps first-order types at runtime, but erases type arguments to generic types at compile time, so you can only reflect on the type constructor ("raw type") but not the type argument. Again, C doesn't have runtime reflection, so it doesn't need to keep the type at runtime.

The only reason to keep the type at runtime in C would be for debugging, however, debugging is usually done with the source available, and then you can simply look up the type in the source file.

Type Erasure is quite normal. It doesn't impact type safety: the types are checked at compile time, once the compiler is satisfied that the program is type-safe, the types are no longer needed (for that reason). It doesn't impact static polymorphism (aka overloading): once overload resolution is complete, and the compiler has picked the right overload, it doesn't need the types anymore. Types can also guide optimization, but again, once the optimizer has picked its optimizations based on the types, it doesn't need them anymore.

Retaining types at runtime is only required when you want to do something with the types at runtime.

Haskell is one of the most strict, most rigorous, type-safe statically typed languages, and Haskell compilers usually erase all types. (The exception being the passing of method dictionaries for type classes, I believe.)

Comment: so you mean in C language the types are handled by the compiler? ok but if I declare lets say: char a = 'A''; there must be still information about if a is char or not somewhere in exe file???

Comment: No! Why? What would that information be needed for? The compiler outputs the code for reading a `char` into the compiled binary. It doesn't output the code for an `int`, it doesn't output the code for a `byte`, it doesn't output the code for a pointer, it simply outputs *only* the code for a `char`. There are no runtime decisions being made based on the type. You don't need the type. It is completely and utterly irrelevant. All relevant decisions have already been made at compile time.

Comment: @user16307 some code - https://ideone.com/PtU10J and its assembly https://goo.gl/dqK15Y .  The compiled code sees no difference between the char and the int other than the size (a byte vs long in intel syntax). That it is different sizes is made at compile time and done.

Comment: but some mentioned here, the assembly and binary code(after compile) includes instructions which address is which type of data?  Read commentator below: "When you write a C program that writes and reads a char variable, the compiler creates assembly code that writes that piece of data somewhere as a char, and there is some other code somewhere else that reads a memory address and interprets it as a char."   What do you say? Im confused again.

Comment: @user16307 do not confuse a difference in the size of bit of data and its type. A float and an int32 are the same, as is a double and int64. However, those are different types.

Comment: @MichaelT ok but doesnt the exe file include information about the type of the data at all at another location??

Comment: @MichaelT I write this for you again: how would you explain if the CPU finds 0x00000061 at a register and fetches it; and imagine the console program supposed to output this as a character not int. do you mean that in that exe file there are some instruction codes which knows the address of 0x00000061 is a char and converts to a character by using ASCII table?

Comment: @user16307 Yes.  Look very closely at that ideone link. Note that the int is printed out as a character, and the character is printed out as a number.

Comment: @MichaelT which line is the instruction code that says "ok this value at this address is actually char" for the register where the char a; stored?

Comment: There isn't. The compiler simply puts code for printing a char in the binary. Period. The compiler knows that at that memory address, there is char, therefore it puts the code for printing a char in the binary. If the value at that memory address for some strange reason happens to *not* be a char, then, well, all hell breaks loose. That's basically how a whole class of security exploits work.

Comment: Think about it: if the CPU somehow knew about the data types of programs, then everybody on the planet would have to buy a new CPU everytime someone invents a new type. `public class JoergsAwesomeNewType {};` See? I just invented a new type! You need to buy a new CPU!

Comment: I dont understand this.... Lets focus on execution part in my question. Doesnt exe file include information about what address is what type of data?

Comment: I cannot find any information about this on web.

Comment: No. It doesn't. The compiler knows what code it has to put in the binary. There is no point in keeping this information around. If you are printing an int, the compiler will put the code for printing an int. If you are printing a char, the compiler will put the code for printing a char. Period. But it's just a bit pattern. The code for printing a char will interpret the bit pattern in a certain way, the code for printing an int will interpret the bit in a different way, but there is no way to distinguish a bit pattern which is an int from a bit pattern which is a char, it's a string of bits.

Comment: @user16307: dont think about stuff regarding exe files, that will just confuse you more. You need to walk before you run.

Comment: @user16307: When your print your `int` or `char` you use something like `printf("%d %c", x, a);` You see, there is difference, but it is included in the first parameter for printf, not in x or a. Take a close look at the links by @MichaelT again.

Comment: @user16307: "Doesnt exe file include information about what address is what type of data?"  Maybe.  If you compile with debug data, the debug data will include information on variable names, addresses, and types.  And sometimes that debug data is stored within the .exe file (as a binary stream).  But it is not part of the executable code, and it is not used by the application itself, only by a debugger.

Answer (score 12):

The computer doesn't "know" what addresses are what, but the knowledge of what's what is baked into the instructions of your program.

When you write a C program that writes and reads a char variable, the compiler creates assembly code that writes that piece of data somewhere as a char, and there is some other code somewhere else that reads a memory address and interprets it as a char. The only thing tying these two operations together is the location of that memory address.

When it comes time to read, the instructions don't say "see what data type is there", it just says something like "load that memory as a float". If the address to be read from has been changed, or something has overwritten that memory with something other than a float, the CPU will just happily load that memory as a float anyway, and all kinds of weird stuff can happen as a result.

Bad analogy time: imagine a complicated shipping warehouse, where the warehouse is memory and people picking things is the CPU. One part of the warehouse 'program' places various items on the shelf. Another program goes and grabs items off the warehouse and puts them into boxes. When they are pulled off, they are not checked, they just go into the bin. The whole warehouse functions by everything working in sync, with the right items always being in the right place at the right time, otherwise everything crashes, just like in an actual program.

Comment: how would you explain if the CPU finds 0x00000061 at a register and fetches it; and imagine the console program supposed to output this as a character not int. do you mean that in that exe file there are some instruction codes which knows the address of  0x00000061 is a char and converts to a character by using ASCII table?

Comment: Note that "everything crashes" is actually the best-case scenario. "Weird things happen" is the second-best scenario, "subtly-weird things happen" is even worse, and the worst-case is "things happen behind your back that someone intentionally manipulated to happen just the way they want them to", aka a security exploit.

Comment: @user16307: The code in the program will tell the computer to fetch that address then to display it according to whatever encoding is being used. Whether that data in the memory location is an ASCII character or complete garbage, the computer is not concerned about. Something else was responsible for setting up that memory address to have the expected values in it. I think it might benefit you to try some assembly programming.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: indeed. I thought about mentioning a buffer overflow as an example but decided it would just make things more confusing.

Comment: @user16307: The thing that displays data to screen is a program. On traditional unixen it's a terminal (a piece of software that emulates the DEC VT100 serial terminal - a hardware device with a monitor and keyboard that displays whatever that comes into its modem to the monitor and sends whatever typed on its keyboard to its modem). On DOS it's DOS (actually the text mode of your VGA card but lets ignore that) and on Windows it's command.com. Your program doesn't know that it's actually printing out strings, it's just printing out a sequence of bytes (numbers).

Comment: It's your terminal (or DOS) that converts those numbers to strings. You can test how "dumb" the system is (in that it doesn't actually know the type of data in memory) by printing out an mp3 or jpeg file to the terminal using `cat`. The `cat` program will dumbly treat the mp3 or jpeg as text and try to print it to screen and the terminal will dumbly believe you that it's text and try to interpret it as ASCII (or if you're lucky, Unicode) and you'll get a bunch of garbage on screen. The computer doesn't know it's garbage. It's only garbage to your (human) eyes.

Comment: Oh. And on GUI programs it's the GUI library that does the conversion. You can still try to print non-text data to a GUI as text and sometimes it will print out garbage but sometimes it would just crash because it wasn't expecting certain bytes (numbers). You can test this out by opening a jpeg in something like notepad (I really wouldn't recommend mp3 because of the typical size of mp3 files)

Comment: @user16307: Actually, when 0x00000061 is output, it is treated as `a` by default.  The display just gets glyph # 97 from the font table, which happens to look like a lowercase A.  If you want to output it as a number, then the compiler will add the extra code for determining the individual decimal digits and sending the corresponding ASCII codes 0x39 0x37... the display looks up the glyphs 47 and 45 and what you see on your screen is `61`.  Of course, it doesn't make sense to repeat this code, so the compiler actually will insert a function call.  A reverse engineer could see that call to

Comment: `itoa` (literally, "integer to ASCII") and deduce that the memory location contains an `int` and not a `char`.  Decompilers can even automate a lot of this.  But it definitely is not true that there is some table giving data types for all memory locations (and except for global variables, memory locations get reused anyway).  Things are different in managed platforms, where objects are tagged with type.  But C and C++ have no such concept.

Comment: if you read under my question the last comments, some commentators claim this story completely different in C++ and C# case. they claim data type identifiers are used during execution do you have information about it?

Comment: @user16307: the answer is "it's complicated". I think you should try writing some assembly programs, as that will really teach you how the computer, as a machine, actually does things.

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't. Once C is compiled to machine code, the machine just sees a bunch of bits. How those bits are interpreted depends on what operations are being performed on them as opposed to some additional metadata.

The types you enter in your source code are just for the compiler. It takes what type you say the data is supposed to be and, to the best of its ability, tries to make sure that that data is only used in ways that make sense. Once the compiler has done as good a job as it can in checking the logic of your source code, it converts it to machine code, and discards the type data, because machine code has no way of representing that (at least on most machines).

Comment: What I don't understand is how does the computer know lets when it reads a variable's value from and address such as 10001 if is an int or char. Imagine I click on a program called anyprog.exe. Immediately the code starts executing. Does this exe file include information about if the variables are stored as in or char? –

Comment: @user16307 No, there's no extra information about if something is an int or a char. I'll add some example stuff later, assuming nobody else beats me to it.

Comment: @user16307: The exe file contains that information indirectly. The processor executing the program doesn't care about the types used when writing the program, but much of it can be deduced from the instructions used to access the various memory locations.

Comment: @user16307 there is actually a little extra information. The exe files knows that an integer is 4 bytes so when you write "int a" the compiler reservers 4 bytes for the a variable and can thus calculate the address of a and the other variables after.

Comment: I think I couldn't put my question well. If program reads a register value it has to interpret via ASCII code if it is char for example if it reads 65 it will out A because it is a char. But if it was int it would out as 65. Isnt it? So I think it has to know of the stored value is int char string ect? Where am I wrong here?

Comment: @user16307 there is no practical difference (beside the size of the type) difference between `int a = 65` and `char b = 'A'` once the code is compiled.

Comment: @user16307: If it is an int and it's value is 65 or if it's a float and it's binary representation is 0x41 it will still print an 'A' if you tell it to treat the value as a char. The computer doesn't know that it's an int or a float. It will do as you tell it to. If you tell it that the float whose binary representation is 0x41 is a char it will believe you an print out 'A'.

Answer (score 6):

Most processors provide different instructions for working with data of different types, so type information is usually "baked in" to the generated machine code.  There's no need to store additional type metadata.

Some concrete examples might help.  The machine code below was generated using gcc 4.1.2 on an x86_64 system running SuSE Linux Enterprise Server (SLES) 10.

Assume the following source code:

```
int main( void )
{
  int x, y, z;

  x = 1;
  y = 2;

  z = x + y;

  return 0;
}
```

Here's the meat of the generated assembly code corresponding to the above source (using `gcc -S`), with comments added by me:

```
main:
.LFB2:
        pushq   %rbp               ;; save the current frame pointer value
.LCFI0:
        movq    %rsp, %rbp         ;; make the current stack pointer value the new frame pointer value
.LCFI1:                            
        movl    $1, -12(%rbp)      ;; x = 1
        movl    $2, -8(%rbp)       ;; y = 2
        movl    -8(%rbp), %eax     ;; copy the value of y to the eax register
        addl    -12(%rbp), %eax    ;; add the value of x to the eax register
        movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)     ;; copy the value in eax to z
        movl    $0, %eax           ;; eax gets the return value of the function
        leave                      ;; exit and restore the stack
        ret
```

There's some extra stuff that follows `ret`, but it isn't relevant to the discussion.

`%eax` is a 32-bit general purpose data register.  `%rsp` is a 64-bit register reserved for saving the *stack pointer*, which contains the address of the last thing pushed onto the stack.  `%rbp` is a 64-bit register reserved for saving the *frame pointer*, which contains the address of the current *stack frame*.  A stack frame is created on the stack when you enter a function, and it reserves space for the function's arguments and local variables.  Arguments and variables are accessed by using offsets from the frame pointer.  In this case, the memory for the variable `x` is 12 bytes "below" the address stored in `%rbp`.

In the above code, we copy the integer value of `x` (1, stored at `-12(%rbp)`) to the register `%eax` using the `movl` instruction, which is used to copy 32-bit words from one location to another.  We then call `addl`, which adds the integer value of `y` (stored at `-8(%rbp)`) to the value already in `%eax`.  We then save the result to `-4(%rbp)`, which is `z`.

Now let's change that up so we're dealing with `double` values instead of `int` values:

```
int main( void )
{
  double x, y, z;

  x = 1;
  y = 2;

  z = x + y;

  return 0;
}
```

Running `gcc -S` again gives us:

```
main:
.LFB2:
        pushq   %rbp                              
.LCFI0:
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
.LCFI1:
        movabsq $4607182418800017408, %rax ;; copy literal 64-bit floating-point representation of 1.00 to rax
        movq    %rax, -24(%rbp)            ;; save rax to x
        movabsq $4611686018427387904, %rax ;; copy literal 64-bit floating-point representation of 2.00 to rax
        movq    %rax, -16(%rbp)            ;; save rax to y
        movsd   -24(%rbp), %xmm0           ;; copy value of x to xmm0 register
        addsd   -16(%rbp), %xmm0           ;; add value of y to xmm0 register
        movsd   %xmm0, -8(%rbp)            ;; save result to z
        movl    $0, %eax                   ;; eax gets return value of function
        leave                              ;; exit and restore the stack
        ret
```

Several differences.  Instead of `movl` and `addl`, we use `movsd` and `addsd` (assign and add double-precision floats).  Instead of storing interim values in `%eax`, we use `%xmm0`.

This is what I mean when I say that the type is "baked in" to the machine code.  The compiler simply generates the right machine code to handle that particular type.

Answer (score 4):

*Historically*, C regarded memory as consisting of a number of groups of numbered slots of type `unsigned char` (also called "byte", though it need not always be 8 bits).  Any code which used anything stored in memory would need to know which slot or slots the information was stored in, and know what should be done with the information there [e.g. "interpret the four bytes starting at address 123:456 as a 32-bit floating-point value" or "store the lower 16 bits of the most recently computed quantity into two bytes starting at address 345:678].  The memory itself would neither know nor care what the values stored in the memory slots "meant".  If code tried to write memory using one type and read it as another, the bit patterns stored by the write would be interpreted according to the rules of the second type, with whatever consequences might result.

For example, if code were to store `0x12345678` to a 32-bit `unsigned int`, and then attempt to read two consecutive 16-bit `unsigned int` values from its address and the one above, then depending upon which half of the `unsigned int` was stored where, the code might read the values 0x1234 and 0x5678, or 0x5678 and 0x1234.

The C99 Standard, however, *no longer requires that memory behave as a bunch of numbered slots that know nothing about what their bit patterns represent*.  A compiler is allowed to behave as though memory slots are aware of the types of data that are stored into them, and will only allow data which is written using any type other than `unsigned char` to be read using either type `unsigned char` or the same type as it was written with; compilers are further allowed to behave as though memory slots have the power and inclination to arbitrarily corrupt the behavior of any program which tries to access memory in a fashion contrary to those rules.

Given:

```
unsigned int a = 0x12345678;
unsigned short p = (unsigned short *)&a;
printf("0x%04X",*p);
```

some implementations might print 0x1234, and others might print 0x5678, but under the C99 Standard it would be legal for an implementation to print "FRINK RULES!" or do anything else, on the theory that it would be legal for the memory locations holding `a` to include hardware that records what type was used to write them, and for such hardware to respond to an invalid read attempt in any fashion whatsoever, including by causing "FRINK RULES!" to be output.

Note that it doesn't matter if any such hardware actually exists--the fact that such hardware could legally exist makes it legal for compilers to generate code which behaves as though it's running on such a system.  If the compiler can determine that a particular memory location will be written as one type and read as another, it can pretend that it's running on a system whose hardware could make such determination, and could respond with whatever degree of capriciousness the compiler author sees fit.

The purpose of this rule was to allow compilers which knew that a group of bytes holding a value of some type held a particular value at some point in time, and that no value of that same type had been written since, to infer that that group of bytes would still hold that value.  For example, a processor had read a group of bytes into a register, and then later on wanted to use the same information again while it was still in the register, the compiler could use the register contents without having to reread the value from memory.  A useful optimization.  For about the first ten years of the rule, violating it would generally mean that if a variable is written with a type other than one which is used to read it, the write may or may not affect the value read.  Such behavior may in some cases be disastrous, but in other cases may be harmless, especially if the code which is reading the value would be equally happy with the value written or the value held before the write, or even more so if the value written happened to match the value already held.

Around 2009, however, the authors of some compilers like CLANG have determined that since the Standard allows compilers to do anything they like in cases where memory is written using one type and read as another, compilers should infer that programs will never receive input that could cause such a thing to occur.  Since the Standard says the compiler is allowed to do anything it likes when such invalid input is received, code which would only have an effect in cases where the Standard imposes no requirements may (and in the view of some compiler authors, should) be omitted as irrelevant.  This changes the behavior of aliasing violations from being like memory that which, given a read request, may arbitrarily return the last value written using the same type as a read request or any more recent value written using some other type, to being like memory which will capriciously alter program behavior any time the Standard would allow it to do so.

Comment: Mentioning undefined behavior when type pruning to someone who doesn't understand how there is no RTTI seems counter-intuitive

Comment: @ColeJohnson: It's too bad there's no formal name or standard for the dialect of C supported by 99% of pre-2009 compilers, since from both a teaching perspective and a practical one they should be considered fundamentally different languages.  Since the same name is given to both the dialect that evolved a number of predictable and optimizable behaviors over 35 years, dialect that throws out such behaviors for the supposed purpose of optimization, it's hard to avoid confusion when talking about things that work differently in them.

Comment: Historically C ran on the Lisp machines that didn't permit such loose playing with types. I'm pretty sure that many of the "predictable and optimizable behaviors" seen 30 years ago simply didn't work anywhere but BSD Unix on the VAX.

Comment: @prosfilaes: Perhaps "99% of the compilers that were used from 1999 to 2009" would be more accurate?  Even when compilers had options for some rather aggressive integer optimizations, they were just that--options.  I don't know that I've ever seen a compiler before 1999 which didn't have a mode that didn't guarantee that given `int x,y,z;` the expression `x*y > z` would never do anything other than return 1 or 0, or where aliasing violations would have any effect other than to let the compiler arbitrarily return either an old or new value.

Comment: @prosfilaes: BTW, the C Standard has historically always allowed any structure to be decomposed into a sequence of `unsigned char` values and have its contents later recreated from that same sequence.  While it would be legal for every type other than `unsigned char` to have padding bits which would indicate the type of any value that has ever been stored as that type, and validate when loading a value that either the the padding bits must be set appropriately for the type, or that all value and padding bits must be zero, there is no legitimate way for a language to track...

Comment: ...where the `unsigned char` values that are used to construct a type "came from".  If a program were to decompose a pointer into an `unsigned char[]`, show its hex contents briefly on the screen, and then erase the pointer, the `unsigned char[]`, and later accept some hex numbers from the keyboard, copy them back to a pointer, and then dereference that pointer, behavior would be well-defined in the case where the number that was typed in matched the number that was displayed.

Comment: I'm somewhat curious, therefore, if something like a Lisp machine could have impose any sort of strict typing semantics on a C program running thereon, other than through the aforementioned use of padding bits.

Comment: @supercat You're demanding semantics that are extremely expensive for architectures that trap on overflow or have garbage collection. C has always valued optimization over portability; if you want Java you know where to find it.

Comment: @prosfilaes: When has any standard-compliant version of C *ever* had a garbage collection that was sufficiently reliable as to render `free` unnecessary?  A compiler may sometimes be able to determine that it would be impossible for certain allocated blocks to ever be used again, but some actions would make it forever impossible to determine with certainty that an abandoned block will never get used again, and nothing in the Standard would indicate what actions could cause memory leaks or erroneous freeing of memory blocks which a program is in fact still going to use.

Comment: @prosfilaes: While I recognize that some platforms have hardware traps on overflow, I don't know of any which legitimately define `int32_t` and `uint32_t` [meaning they have 32-bit types with no padding] where evaluating `x*y > z` with type `int32_t` so as to always yield 1 or 0 (with no other effect) would be more expensive than doing so with `uint32_t`, though I know of some where being allowed to arbitrarily return 1 or 0 would allow code for `int` to be more efficient code than code for `uint32_t`. While an option to trap on integer overflow would be helpful for some applications...

Comment: ...being able to use a behavioral model where integer overflows yield partially-indeterminate values with loosely-defined semantics would be helpful in many others.  Java requires that `x<<y` must yield `x<<(y & 31)`.  Hyper-modernists would like programmers who would write `x<<y` to instead write either `x<<(y & 31)`, `y > 31 ? 0 : x<<y`,  `(y & 224) ? 0 : x<<(y & 31)`, or some other variation thereof, *even if the programmer wouldn't care whether `x<<32` yielded `x` or `0`*.  I'd like to say `x<<y` can arbitrarily yield whichever of the indicated forms is fastest on the CPU being used.

Comment: @supercat When you say "historically", I think of the 20 years prior to any C standard, not C89. The Lisp Machines were pre-C89, for example. Looking around, it doesn't seem like the differences here are between C89 and C99. I'm sure the C compiler writers would be happy to offer a switch giving the semantics you want if someone was willing to write it.

Answer (score 3):

In C, it is not. Other languages (e.g., Lisp, Python) have dynamic types but C is statically-typed. That means that your program must know what type the data is to properly interpret is as a character, an integer, etc.

Usually the compiler takes care of this for you, and if you do something wrong, you'll get a compile-time error (or warning).

Comment: What I don't understand is how does the computer know lets when it reads a variable's value from and address such as 10001 if is an int or char. Imagine I click on a program called anyprog.exe. Immediately the code starts executing. Does this exe file include information about if the variables are stored as in or char? –

Comment: @user16307 Essentially no, all that information is completely lost.  It's up to the machine code to be designed well enough to do its job right even without that information.  All the computer cares about is that there are eight bits in a row at address `10001`.  It is either **your** job or the **compiler's** job, case depending, to keep up with stuff like that manually while writing machine or assembly code.

Comment: Note that dynamic typing is not the only reason to retain types. Java is statically typed, but it still must retain the types, because it allows to dynamically reflect on the type. Plus, it has runtime polymorphism, i.e. method dispatch based on the runtime type, for which it also needs the type. C++ puts the method dispatch code into the object (or rather class) itself, so, it doesn't need the type in some sense (although of course the vtable is in some sense part of the type, so, really at least part of the type *is* retained), but in Java, the method dispatch code is centralized.

Comment: look at my question I wrote "when a C program executes?" arent they indirectly stored in exe file among instruction codes and eventually take places in memory? I write this for you again: If the CPU finds 0x00000061 at a register and fetches it; and imagine the console program supposed to output this as a character not int. are there in that exe file(machine/binary code) some instruction codes which knows the address of 0x00000061 is a char and converts to a character by using ASCII table? If so it means char int identifiers are indirectly in the binary???

Comment: If the value is 0x61 and is declared as a char (i.e., 'a') and you call a routine to display it, there will [eventually] be a system call to display that character. If you've declared it as an int and call the display routine, the compiler will know to generate code to convert 0x61 (decimal 97) to the ASCII sequence 0x39, 0x37 ('9', '7'). Bottom line: the code that is generated is different because the compiler knows to treat them differently.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: The addition of `dynamic_cast` to C++ means that all polymorphic types must, from a semantic point of view, descend from a common type which supports, for every other polymorphic type, a "convert yourself to a T* if possible or else report that you can't" method.  While it may be possible for a compiler/linker combination might examines a program and determine that various families of polymorphic types aren't ever converted to anything else, and create a separate "base type" for each such family, rather than one unified base type for all polymorphic types, ...

Comment: ...such behavior would be essentially indistinguishable from that of a single unified base type which included a templated "dynamic_cast" method, and a templated static method which given a `T*` would check if it was null and either return null or invoke the appriorate dynamic cast method on it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to distinguish between `compiletime` and `runtime` on the one hand and `code` and `data` on the other hand.

From a machine perspective it is no difference between what you call `code` or `instructions` and what you call `data`. It all comes down to numbers. But some sequences - what we would call `code` - do something what we find usefull, others would simply `crash` the machine.

The work which is done by the CPU is a simple 4 step loop:

- Fetch "data" from a *given* address
- Decode the instruction (i.e. "interpret" the number as an `instruction`)
- Read an effective address
- Execute and store results

This is called the [instruction cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_cycle).

> I read that A and 4 are stored in RAM addresses here. But what about a and x?

`a` and `x` are variables, which are placeholders for the addresses, where the program could find the "content" of the variables. So, anytime the variable `a` is used, there is *effectively* the address of the content of `a` used.

> Most confusingly, how does the execution know that a is a char and x is an int?

The execution doesn't know anyting. From what was said in the introduction, the CPU only fetches data and interprets this data as instructions.

The [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)-function is designed to "know", what kind of input you are putting into it, i.e. its resulting code gives the right instructions how to deal with a special memory segment. Of course, it is possible to gnerate nonsense output: using an address, where no string is stored along with "%s" in `printf()` will result in nonsense output stopped only by a random memory location, where a *0* (`\0`) is.

The same goes for the entry-point of a programm. Under the C64 it was possible to put your programs in (nearly) every known address. Assembly-Programs were started with an instruction called `sys` followed by an address: `sys 49152` was a common place to put your assembler code. But nothing prevented you from loading e.g. graphical data into `49152`, resulting in a machine crash after "starting" from this point. In this case, the *instruction cycle* started with reading "graphical data" and trying to interpret it as "code" (which of course made no sense); the effects were sometmes astounding ;)

> Let's say a value is stored somewhere in RAM as 10011001; if I am the program which executes the code, how will I know whether this 10011001 is a char or an int?

As said: The "context" - i.e. the previous and next instructions - help treating the data in the way we want it. From a machine perspective, there is no difference in any memory location. `int` and `char` is only vocabulary, which makes sense in `compiletime`; during `runtime` (on a assembly level), there is no `char` or `int`.

> What I don't understand is how the computer knows, when it reads a variable's value from an address such as 10001, whether it is an int or char.

The computer *knows* nothing. The *programmer* does. The compiled code generates the *context*, which is necessary to generate meaningful results for humans.

> Does this executable file include information on whether the variables stored are of the type int or char

*Yes* and *No*. The information, whether it is an `int` or a `char` is lost. But on the other hand, the *context* (the instructions which tell, how to deal with memory locations, where data is stored) is preserved; so *implicitely* yes, the "information" is *implicitely* available.

Comment: Nice distinction between compile time & runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Let us keep this discussion to the **C** language only.

The program you are referring to is written in a high level language like C. The computer understand machine language only.
Higher level languages gives the programmer the ability to express logic in a more human friendly way which is then translated into machine code which the microprocessor can decode and execute.
Now let us discuss the code you mentioned:

```
char a = 'A';
int x = 4;
```

Let us try to analyse each part:

> **char/int** are known as data types. These tell the compiler to allocate memory. In the case of `char` it will be 1 byte and `int` 2 bytes. ( Please
>   note this memory size is again depend upon microprocessor ).
>
> **a/x** are known as identifiers. Now these are you can say "user friendly" names given to memory locations in RAM.
>
> **=** tells the compiler to store 'A' at the memory location of `a` and 4 at memory location `x`.

So int/char data type identifiers are only used by the compiler and not by the microprocessor during program execution. Hence they are not stored in memory.

Comment: ok int/char data type identifiers are not directly stored in memory as variables, but arent they indirectly stored in exe file among instruction codes and eventually take places in memory? I write this for you again: If the CPU finds 0x00000061 at a register and fetches it; and imagine the console program supposed to output this as a character not int. are there in that exe file(machine/binary code) some instruction codes which knows the address of 0x00000061 is a char and converts to a character by using ASCII table?  If so it means char int identifiers are indirectly in the binary???

Comment: No for CPU its all numbers. For your specific example printing on console is does not depend upon if variable is char or int. I will update my answer with detail flow of how high level program is converted into machine language till execution of program.

Answer (score 2):

*My answer here is somewhat simplified and will refer only to C.*

### No, type information does not get stored in the program.

`int` or `char` are not type indicators to the CPU; only to the compiler.

The exe created by the compiler will have instructions to manipulate `int`s if the variable was declared as an `int`. Likewise, if the variable was declared as a `char`, the exe will contain instructions to manipulate a `char`.

In C:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 65;
    char b = 'A';
    if(a == b)
    {
        printf("Well, what do you know. A char can equal an int.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This program **will print** its message, since the `char` and the `int` have the **same *values*** in RAM.

Now, if you are wondering how `printf` manages to output `65` for an `int` and `A` for a `char`, that is because you have to specify in the "format string" how `printf` should treat the *value*.
(For example, `%c` means to treat the value as a `char`, and `%d` means to treat the value as an integer; same value either way, though.)

Comment: I was hoping someone would use an example using `printf`. @OP: `int a = 65; printf("%c", a)` will output `'A'`. Why? Because the processor doesn't care. To it, all it sees are bits. Your program told the processor to store 65 (coincidentally the value of `'A'` in ASCII) at `a` and then output a character, which is gladly does. Why? Because it doesn't care.

Comment: but why some says here in C# case, it is not the story? i read some others comments and they say in C# and C++ the story(info on data types) is different and even CPU does not do the computing. Any ideas about that?

Comment: @user16307 If the CPU doesn't do the computing, the program isn't running. :) As for C#, I don't know, but I think my answer applies there too. As for C++, I know my answer applies there.

Answer (score 0):

At the lowest level, in the actual physical CPU there are no types at all (ignoring the floating point units). Just patterns of bits. A computer works by manipulating patterns of bits, very, very fast.

That's all the CPU ever does, all it ever can do. There's no such thing as an int, or a char.

```
x = 4 + 5
```

Will execute as:

1. Load  00000100 into register 1
2. Load  00000101 into register 2
3. IAdd register 1 to register 2, and store in register 1

The iadd instruction triggers hardware which behaves as if registers 1 and 2 are integers. If they don't actually represent integers, all kinds of things can go wrong later. The best outcome is usually crashing.

It's on the compiler to chose the correct instruction based on the types given in source, but in the actual machine code executed by the CPU, there are no types, anywhere.

edit: Note that the actual machine code does not in fact mention 4, or 5, or integer anywhere. it's just two patterns of bits, and an instruction that takes two bit patterns, assumes they're ints, and adds them together.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, the type is encoded in the CPU instructions the compiler generates.

Although the information about the type or size of the information is not directly stored, the compiler does keep track of this information when accessing, modifying and storing values in these variables.

> how does the execution know that a is a char and x is an int?

It doesn't, but when the compiler produces the machine code it knows. An `int` and a `char` can be of different sizes. In an architecture where where a char is the size of a byte and an int is 4 bytes, then variable `x` is not in address 10001, but also in 10002, 10003 and 10004. When code needs to load the value of `x` into a CPU register, it uses the instruction for loading 4 bytes. When loading a char, it uses the instruction to load 1 byte.

How to choose which of the two instructions? The compiler decides during the compilation, it's not done at runtime after inspecting the values in memory.

Note as well that registers can be of different sizes. On Intel x86 CPUs the EAX is 32 bits wide, half of it is AX, which is 16, and AX is split into AH and AL, both 8 bits.

So if you want to load an integer (on x86 CPUs), you use the MOV instruction for integers, to load a char you use the MOV instruction for chars. They are both called MOV, but they have different op codes. Effectively being two different instructions. The type of the variable is encoded in the instruction to use.

The same thing happens with other operations. There are many instructions for performing addition, depending on the size of operands, and even if they are signed or unsigned. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADD_(x86_instruction) which list different possible additions.

> Let's say a value is stored somewhere in RAM as 10011001; if I am the program which executes the code, how will I know whether this 10011001 is a char or an int

First, a char would be 10011001, but an int would be 00000000 00000000 00000000 10011001, because they are different sizes (on a computer with the same sizes as mentioned above). But lets consider the case for `signed char` vs `unsigned char`.

What is stored in a memory location can be interpreted anyway you want. Part of the responsibilities of the C compiler is to ensure that what is stored and read from a variable is done in a consistent manner. So it's not that the program knows what's stored in a memory location, but that it agrees before hand that it will always read and write the same kind of things there. (not counting things like casting types).

Comment: but why some says here in C# case, it is not the story? i read some others comments and they say in C# and C++ the story(info on data types) is different and even CPU does not do the computing. Any ideas about that?

Answer (score 0):

> but why some says here in C# case, it is not the story? i read some others comments and they say in C# and C++ the story(info on data types) is different and even CPU does not do the computing. Any ideas about that?

In type-checked languages like C#, the type-checking is done by the compiler. The code benji wrote:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 65;
    char b = 'A';
    if(a == b)
    {
        printf("Well, what do you know. A char can equal an int.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Would simply refuse to compile. Similarly if you tried to multiply a string and an integer (I was going to say add, but the operator '+' is overloaded with string concatenation and it might just work).

```
int a = 42;
string b = "Compilers are awesome.";
double[] c = a * b;
```

The compiler would simply refuse to generate machine code from this C#, no matter how much your string kissed up to it.

Answer (score -4):

The other answers are correct in that essentially every consumer device you will encounter doesn't store type information. However, there have been several hardware designs in the past (and the present day, in a research context) that use a [tagged architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_architecture) -- they store both the data and the type (and possibly other information as well). These would most prominently include the [Lisp machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_machine).

I vaguely recall hearing about a hardware architecture designed for object-oriented programming that had something similar, but I can't find it now.

Comment: The question specifically states it is referring to the C language (not Lisp), and the C language does _not_ store variable metadata. While it is certainly possible for a C implementation to do this, as the standard does not forbid it, in practice it never happens. If you have examples relevant to the question, please provide specific citations and provide references _that relate to the C language_.

Comment: Well, you could write a C compiler for a Lisp machine, but nobody uses Lisp machines in this day and age in general. The object-oriented architecture was [Rekursiv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rekursiv), by the way.

Comment: I think this answer isn't helpful. It complicates things way beyond the current level of understanding of the OP. It's clear the OP doesn't understand the basic execution model of a CPU + RAM, and how a compiler translates symbolic high-level source to an executable binary. Tagged memory, RTTI, Lisp, etc, is way beyond what the asker needs to know in my opinion, and will only confuse him/her more.

Comment: but why some says here in C# case, it is not the story? i read some others comments and they say in C# and C++ the story(info on data types) is different and even CPU does not do the computing. Any ideas about that?