# Why do we need to specify the type of data a pointer will hold, if all pointers are the same

Tags: c, memory, pointers, memory-usage, smart-pointer

Why do we need to specify the type of the data whose address, a pointer will hold, if all pointers are the same.
Since all pointers store addresses.
Also, the amount of space a pointer will require in memory depends on whether the machine is 32-bit or 64-bit.

Suppose my pointer ptr stores the address of an int and my machine is 64-bit.
So, inside of my pointer ptr, I see a 8-byte (64-bit address) say, 0x123456789ABCDEF0.

Lets suppose we have a box which is labelled as ptr and it contains this (0x123456789ABCDEF0) no which is the address of an int. Now, this address (0x123456789ABCDEF0) doesn't specify if its an address of an int or char or float or double or anything else its just an address in RAM. So how does anyone else know that the pointer points to an int if they are just told that ptr is a pointer and the address it contains is (0x123456789ABCDEF0)?

Comment: Well, your premise is wrong: Not all pointers are equal (though your ABI may guarantee more than the language-standard), and I'm not even talking of the distinction between data- and functions-pointers.

Comment: Your first paragraph answers your third paragraph and your third paragraph answers your first paragraph.

Comment: I mean look, ptr has, say 64-bits to store something. All it stores is a 64-bit location in memory. Now, it has no space to store any other information. So, where is the int or char or float or double part?

Comment: @tkausl please explain a bit more. Where is that information which tells you that ptr contains the address of an int?                                                                            
I mean, can I tell that the pointer has the address of an int, just by looking at a box which is labelled as ptr and has 0x123456789ABCDEF0 as its content?

Comment: No you can't, thats why we specify the type as `int*`, and not as `void*` or any other generic pointer type.

Comment: @AhmadNasir: the information is baked into the instructions of the program. See here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/291950/are-data-type-declarators-like-int-and-char-stored-in-ram-when-a-c-program-e

Comment: Surely the reason that we type pointers is **because** a `void*` could point to anything? It's helpful to type them for that very reason.

Comment: @AhmadNasir There have been machines where most pointers are 32 bit, but char* and void* are 64 bit.

Answer (score 15):

From the memory-allocation point-of-view, you're right. A pointer variable on a 64-bit architecture occupies 8 bytes, no matter what type of pointer it is.

But the C compiler needs to know more about a variable than its size. An analogy: `long` and `float` typically both need 4 bytes (so why have different types???), but you surely tell the compiler which one you want because their **operations behave differently**.

Back to pointers: there is the `*` operator for dereferencing a pointer, and the `[]` indexing operator for relative addressing, and both need to know the pointer type.

For a pointer declared `int *pi;`, a statement like `double x = *pi / 2` will truncate the division, while with a `float *pf;`, `float x = *pf / 2` will give you a fractional result. So you surely need to tell the compiler about the pointer type, for some quite important **behaviour depends on that info**.

And there is pointer arithmetic, e.g. the relative addressing done with the `[]` operator. If we have

```
char   *pc = 0x12340; // Compiler will complain, as types don't match!
int    *pi = 0x12340;
double *pd = 0x12340;
```

Then, `pc[4]` will be the character (byte) you find four characters after the `0x12340` address, being at `0x12344`. But you'll find `pd[4]` not at `0x12344`, but at `0x12360`, 32 bytes after the base address, as indexing a double pointer will count in 8-byte steps instead of single bytes. And of course this also applies to all of the pointer arithmetic including the `+` and `-` operators. So, once again, you need to tell the compiler about the pointer type to allow for correct pointer arithmetic.

One important feature of the C language is that the type information is kept only in the compiler. At runtime, the `pi` pointer's 8 bytes in memory don't contain the information that `pi` is an `int` pointer. It's the compiler that produces different machine code for operations on pointers of different types.

So, if you get a pointer with value `0x123456789ABCDEF0` and no other information, you can't tell if it's a `double`, an `int` or a function pointer (or whatever else). Only if your compiled code contains a "debug" attachment, you might find the info there that the `pi` variable is an `int` pointer, and if your `0x123456789ABCDEF0` pointer value comes from that variable, then you know that you have to look for a (4-byte?) `int` starting at the address of `0x123456789ABCDEF0` if you want to see the value that `pi` points to.

But such a debug attachment is by no means necessary for the program to run, it's just a courtesy for people who want to look inside.

Comment: Good answer, but consider to add a word about pointer arithmetics, that is the other important operation (besides dereferencing) which requires knowledge of the type.

Comment: @DocBrown Good suggestion. I started to mention the indexing operator (as an example of pointer arithmetic), but didn't explain more about it.

Comment: There's also the `->` operator, which wouldn't work without knowing which structure it should dig into.

Comment: "A pointer variable on a 64 bit architecture occupies 8 bytes" - there are different architectures. The C Standard only requires that char* and void* have the same representation, all struct* have the same representation, all union*, all pointers to variants of short, all pointers to variants of int, of long, of long long.

Comment: What about Itanium? It's a 64 bit architecture, but function-pointers are 128 bits (address of function, value of data base register or whatever). On some ABIs though, pointers to costants containing that are used.

Comment: @gnasher729: Even on 64bit machines, a member function pointer is usually >64 bits.

Comment: I don't think this is correct because you can declare a pointer to an incomplete type i.e. you can declare a pointer to a class that you have declared but not defined. The compiler has no idea how big the class is, but it still allows you to declare a pointer to it.